# Switching languages

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, language

I'm a translator, I type in Russian and frequently check online dictionaries. I just got a laptop with Windows 10 and encountered an unfamiliar problem. When I switch between Word (really old version) and Chrome, the input language doesn't change into English. I never had this problem in Win 7 or XP. I want to type in Word in Russian and search the Internet in English as default. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Defining your Word version is nothing to be ashamed of; it will help someone writing a reasonable answer to your question. However, if you are using Word 2010 or above (2007 could work as well), you can define the default  editing language to something you prefer. For older versions, I may check it out if I'm given the version year.

Comment: Hi Sanny, I think it's Office XP so about 2000-2001.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide-through that should work for Chrome. Regarding using Office XP, I will write what I can remember and using screenshots from the Web (I don't use Office XP). I'm just surprised that you are using a-decade-old something in Windows 10.

**Note:** I believe since Windows 7, Windows remembers the current input language for each programme in the task bar. If you switch Chrome's input language to Russian, moved from Chrome to Word and then return to Chrome, Chrome will still use Russian because you left it on Russian.

**Set System Input Method to be the Default Language for Chrome**

Well, you can't set the default language for Chrome so it will use the system's default input language. Open Control Panel, then under `Clock, Language and Region`, click `Change input method`. On the left pane, click on `Advanced settings`.

In the drop-down list under `Override for default input method`, choose an English locale that likely suits your keyboard mapping, e.g. English (United States). Confirm your changes by clicking button `Save`.

Now Chrome, like every programme in your computer, will launch using English (United States).

**Set Enabled Languages in Office XP**

Basically you can change Office XP interface language to Russian. That would launch Word using Russian as input language. Search in Start menu for `Microsoft Office XP Language Settings` (nested at `Start > All apps > Microsoft Office Tools > Microsoft Office XP Language Settings`).

In tab `Enabled Languages`, from the drop-down list `Default version of Microsoft Office:`, choose Russian.

[image: Source: scripts.sil.org/]

If Russian is not available, or you prefer using English interface, *try* removing extra languages in list `Enabled Languages` and limiting it to English and Russian only.

Restart your computer (if you have to).